# Nativescript listview disable components reusing

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have a `ListView` of custom components that receive a boolean `@Input()` property which is responsible of displaying some parts of the template.

This is the `ListView` :

```
<ListView [items]="photos">
    <ng-template let-item="item">
        <app-post [photo]="item" [displayInfo]="display"></app-post>
    </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

The `display` variable is set to `false`.

And this is the `app-post` template :

```
<StackLayout *ngIf="displayInfo" verticalAlignment="center">
....            
</StackLayout>
```

Where `displayInfo` is the input property.
Inside the `app-post` component I have logic that changes the `displayInfo` value to true.
I noticed however that the `ListView` only creates a couple of components and than reuses them as scrolling down. 
This causes the following (example) scenario :

1. List of 5 `app-post` components, all with `displayInfo` to false
2. Click on 1st `app-post` component sets `displayInfo` to true
3. 3d and 5th `app-post` components have already `displayInfo` set to
   true

How can I avoid this behaviour and have all custom components with the property set to the value specified with in the listview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NativeScript ListView is virtualized and is using recycling for its cells which are causing your issue as you are expecting the custom components to be as originally created in your list while, in fact, they are part of list cells that are being reused.

The solution is to introduce the `displayInfo` boolean as a part of your items model. [Here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4469#issuecomment-334079192) is a similar solution explained for TypeScript project but the very same concept could be used in Angular based project

Comment: This makes sense! Will try and let you know :)